# C++-Tokenizer extremely slow

Tags: c++

I just don't get what i do wrong. The unicode tokenizer function shown below  is very very slow. Maybe somebody can give me a hint how to speed it up? 
Thanks for any help. By the way, `ustring` is `Glib::ustring`.
`sep1` are separators that should not show up in the results
`sep2` are separators that should be single tokens in the result

```
void tokenize(const ustring & u, const ustring & sep1, 
        const ustring & sep2, vector<ustring> & tokens) {
    ustring s;
    s.reserve(100);
    ostringstream os;
    gunichar c;
    for (int i = 0; i < u.length(); i++) {
        c = u[i];
        if (sep1.find(c) != ustring::npos) {
            tokens.push_back(s);
            s = "";
        }
        else if (sep2.find(c) != ustring::npos) {
            tokens.push_back(s);
            s = "";
            s.append(1, c);
            tokens.push_back(s);
            s = "";
        }
        else {
            s.append(1, c);
        }
    }
    if (s!="")
    tokens.push_back(s);
}
```

I now changed it to (now between 1 and 2 seconds) :

```
ustring s;
s.reserve(100);
ostringstream os;
gunichar c;

set<gunichar> set_sep1;
int i=0;

for (i=0;i<sep1.size();i++)
{
    set_sep1.insert(sep1[i]);
}

set<gunichar> set_sep2;
for (i=0;i<sep2.size();i++)
{
    set_sep2.insert(sep2[i]);
}

int start_index=-1;
int ulen=u.length();
i=0;
for (ustring::const_iterator it=u.begin();it!=u.end();++it)
{
    c=*it;
    if (set_sep1.find(c)!=set_sep1.end())
    {
        if (start_index!=-1 && start_index<i)
            tokens.push_back(u.substr(start_index,i-start_index));
        start_index=i+1;
        s="";
    }
    else if (set_sep2.find(c)!=set_sep2.end())
    {
        tokens.push_back(s);
        s="";
        tokens.push_back(s);
        start_index=i+1;
        s="";
    }
    i++;
}
if (start_index!=-1 && start_index<ulen)
    tokens.push_back(u.substr(start_index,ulen-start_index));
```

Comment: One thing you could do is not using frequent `.append()` calls and start using indices. I.e. store the index of the begin of a token inside a variable and as soon as you encounter the end of the token do a `tokens.push_back(u.substr(start, end - start))`. Using iterators could be better than this method though...

Comment: Have you profiled your code? Where does the profiler locate bottlenecks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The to things that may be "very very slow" here are:

1. `ustring::length()`
2. `ustring::append()`
3. Random access to `ustring` via `operator[]` : e.g. `c=u[i];`

Try the following:

1. Instead of calling `u.length()` in a loop, store the length in a variable and in the loop compare to that variable
2. Append the characters of the current token to an `ostringstream` or `wostringstream` instead of a ustring
3. Iterate through `ustring` using iterators instead of indices involving random access.

Example:

```
for(ustring::const_iterator it = u.cbegin(); it != u.cend(); it++)
{
    c = *it;
    //implementation follows
}
```

Comment: very good, thanks a lot, runtime decreased from 22 seconds to 1.67 seconds

Comment: @TimvorderBrück, have you replaced `ustring::append` with `wostringstream` too, or only changed from random access to iteration? 1.67 seconds in the world of computations is a lot of time, unless you are processing gigabytes of data in memory or hundreds of megabytes on disk.

Comment: see my modified program

Comment: further decrease to 1 second if I use s.append(1,c) instead of using indices to extract a substring. But can I append gunichars to a wostringstream ?

Comment: @TimvorderBrück, I don't know. Maybe `Glib` provides something like `ustringstream` etc. Why don't you use `std::wstring` by the way?

Answer (score 1):

I think the following will speed up your code significantly, but it's a little work to find out.  Currently you are:

1. iterating over each character of u.
2. doing a find in sep1 to see if that character is among the separators.
3. appending one character at a  time, as needed.

Assuming your list of separators is smaller than the strings you are parsing, you are probably better off doing the following:

1. For each seperator, do a find to see if the separator is in the string
2. If found, append the entire substring in one go, and do a find on the remaing substring.

A second optimization is to order your separators in terms of most likely to succeed.  If for e.g. "," is the most commonly use separator, make sure the find runs on that first.  If one separator is much hotter than others, this will make a big difference.